# Get words from dictionary, content provider, Android

Tags: android, mysql, dictionary, android-contentprovider

I am doing this to get all words from the dictionary that include a string that I pass to the function:

```
public Cursor searchWords(String s) {

    String[] mSelectionArgs = {""};
    String mSearchString = s;
    String mSelectionClause = null;
    String[] mProjection =
        {
            "_id",
            UserDictionary.Words.WORD
        };
    final String mSortOrder = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " ASC";
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchString)) {
        mSelectionClause = null;
        mSelectionArgs[0] = "";
    } else {
        mSelectionClause = UserDictionary.Words.WORD + " LIKE ? ";
        mSelectionArgs[0] = "%"+mSearchString+"%";

    }
    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
            mProjection,
            mSelectionClause,
            mSelectionArgs,
            mSortOrder);

    return mCursor;
}
```

The result is always an empty Cursor.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This code is surprisingly difficult to follow due to the peculiar naming convention. If you want your argument to be called `mSearchString`, declare it that way in the signature. Don't create a copy for no reason.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I copied this code from https://developer.android.com and I removed all the comments before copying it here because I found it a bit difficult to read. The code works perfectly.

Comment: Check my answer :)

Comment: If it works perfectly you wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: When I posted it, the program wasn't working. I imagined that it was a problem with the code, but the real problem was another. It is explained in my answer. Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

The code is correct, the problem is that my **personal dictionary** was empty.

I was expecting the device to use his own dictionary or something like that.

To access to your personal dictionary in Android you have to do:

```
Settings > Idiom > Personal dictionary
```

There you can edit, delete, add... words to it.

This is the way to do it in my Android device, maybe yours is different.